# print array without numerical indexes

Tags: php, arrays

```
$sql = "select id, status, date...from arts order by date desc limit 300";
$st = $db->prepare($sql);
$st->execute();
$arr = $st->fetchAll();

print_r($arr);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2272
            [0] => 2272
            [status] => sky
            [1] => sky
        )

    [1] => Array ...
```

How to get the same but without numerical indexes, like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2272
            [status] => sky
        )

    [1] => Array ...
```

lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum

Comment: You could iterate through the array and check if the key is an integer, unset it.

Comment: why are you adding the same value with numperic index?

Comment: @JarlikStepsto, I didn't add anything, just `print_r` of an array

Comment: if i create an assoc array, without numeric key, print_r does not print any. If you want to filter out the numeric key, see answer of @Pervaiz Iqbal else, check, how you are creating the array

Comment: @JarlikStepsto, Parvaiz answer is resulting in an empty array. All elements are removed.

Comment: Where did the array come from to start with? Is it from a database?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, yes, it's a result of an mysql query

Comment: Then you should simply fetch the result differently. No need to do this manually at all. Show us the db code and we can help you sort it out properly.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, I add the code for getting the array

Comment: Change `$arr = $st->fetchAll();` to `$arr = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` and you should be set. Read more [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) about fetch styles.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, excellent, pls place the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to do this manually. Just let PDO know how you want the result.

Change

```
$arr = $st->fetchAll();
```

to

```
$arr = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

and you should be set. [Read more in the manual about fetch styles](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php).

Answer (score 0):

user this function to get non numeric values

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (is_int($key)) {
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you test this? It is a multidimensional array where the keys are all integers so that will result in an empty array.

Comment: result is an empty array

Comment: The OP has a multidimensional array. It's the inner arrays that should be filtered.

Comment: You will have to run 2 loops in that case. Edited the reply to make this happen

Answer (score 0):

You will have to run 2 loops and unset the piece.

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $keyx => $valuex) {
        if (is_int($keyx)) {
            unset($arr[$key][$keyx]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but that's too much for just a simple task. Can't believe that there is no a function or an argument inside `print_r` to escape num indexes

Comment: `array_filter` as well can do the trick to skip one of the loops.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method I can think of (except for Magnus approach) is probably array_diff_key.
I add this answer as someone else may need a non DB solution later.

Create a range of possible numeric keys.
I created 100, change to suit your needs.

```
$range = range(0,100); 

foreach($arr as &$sub){
    $sub = array_diff_key($sub, $range);
}
```

This will loop through each subarray and filter out any numeric keys from 0-100.